# How do I progress in the cave at the Trading Post?

Tags: zelda-spirit-tracks

I'm in the cave at the back of the Trading Post, looking for the Regal Ring. I've played the Song of Light to 2 crystals so that they made an X. I've stood at the X, and played the Songs of Awakening, Light, Discovery and even Healing, but nothing happens. What am I supposed to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After activating the beacons with the Song of Light, go to the spot where their beams cross. Then, walk 4 tiles to the north and 6 tiles to the west and play the Song of Discovery. This should cause a chest with a Regal Ring to appear.

Comment: This definitely did it. Wow - that spot sure was a ways away from where x marked the spot. Do you have any idea why the spots are so far apart?

Comment: You should have a letter from Linebeck that probably lead you there in the first place. It contains the clues that you need to find the ring, including "go 4 steps north and 6 steps west from where the lights cross".